# maximizing images scroll in background is observed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

please check the plugin

http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#image-gallery

HTML :

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <a href="http://25.media.tumblr.com/de356cd6570d7c26e73979467f296f67/tumblr_mrn3dc10Wa1r1thfzo6_1280.jpg" data-gallery="global-gallery" data-parent="" data-toggle="lightbox">
                <figure>
                    <img src="//25.media.tumblr.com/de356cd6570d7c26e73979467f296f67/tumblr_mrn3dc10Wa1r1thfzo6_400.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <figcaption>@gregfoster</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="http://distilleryimage10.ak.instagram.com/85c5d0e4039411e3bd9b22000aa82186_7.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="global-gallery" data-parent="">
                <img src="//distilleryimage10.ak.instagram.com/85c5d0e4039411e3bd9b22000aa82186_7.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="http://25.media.tumblr.com/de356cd6570d7c26e73979467f296f67/tumblr_mrn3dc10Wa1r1thfzo6_1280.jpg" data-gallery="global-gallery" data-parent="" data-toggle="lightbox">
                <figure>
                    <img src="//25.media.tumblr.com/de356cd6570d7c26e73979467f296f67/tumblr_mrn3dc10Wa1r1thfzo6_400.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <figcaption>@gregfoster</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$(document).delegate('*[data-toggle="lightbox"]', 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).ekkoLightbox();
});
```

Working fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8900/

In the above code i had implemented image slider with bootstrap modal with previous and next buttons as you can see.so now what my problem is when i click image the modal popup opens with a image but at background the sliding of images must be stopped temporarily untill the popup is closed..but it is not happening...so anyone throw some light on it.

Comment: @Gorostas  anyone there to answer this question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not find anything if this plugin exposes any event, so bootstrap modal events it is.
On modal show pause carousel and on modal hide restart it.

```
var carousel = $('#myCarousel');
var body = $('body');

body.on('show.bs.modal', '.ekko-lightbox', function () {    
    carousel.carousel('pause');
})

body.on('hide.bs.modal', '.ekko-lightbox', function () {    
    carousel.carousel('cycle');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9560/

Comment: can you give me a fiddle of it if possible??

Comment: added the link at the bottom of answer